# Are the following Hamiltonian actions?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, toric-geometry

Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinate of $\mathbb{C}^2 \subset \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$. Is the $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ given by 
$$
t\cdot(x,y)=(tx,t^{-1}y)
$$
Hamiltonian? Likewise let $(x,y)$ be the coordinate of $\mathbb{C}^2 \subset \mathbb{P}^2$. Is the same action Hamiltonian on $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Here we consider toric symplectic structures and naturally extend the above $T^1$-action on the compactification.

Comment: http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~berline/cours-Fudan.pdf See page 17, indeed your two examples are from the standard $T^n$ action on $\mathbb P^n$.